# Panantukan numbered template?

Tags: escrima, kali

In the Kali I've done, we do a 12 angle pattern for stick and knife.
The knife pattern has some analogs to the stick pattern, but is not exactly the same due to the different capabilities of the weapon.
I've also done some Panantukan patterns as a part of Kali, but I haven't seen a 12 angle pattern for this "weapon".  Does such a thing exist?  What are the hand-strikes and numbers?  I'm open to Arnis and Escrima answers as well, but answerers please note what system you're coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was doing *Doce Pares* escrima in California about 10 years ago, my instructor taught it to us as knife-hand strikes for 1-4, straight fist punches for 5-10, a hammer-fist blow for 11, and either a punch or a two-finger poke for 12. 7 and 8 were outliers in that the movement was different with it being a straight strike rather than a looping one. He also taught, as an alternative, doing this as a hammerfist blow to the side of the knee or an inside ridge-hand to the back of the knee. All of the blows were done with the same hand for the set of 12, then switched to practice the other hand.

- 1,2 - Knife-hand strike to the temple (forehand and backhand)
- 3,4 - Knife-hand strike to the side of the neck (forehand and backhand)
- 5,6 - Closed-fist punch to the solar plexus (the only difference was which foot you advance on)
- 7,8 - Closed-fist punch to the side of the knee (alternately, he suggested a hammerfist to the same target or a ridgehand to the back of the knee)
- 9,10 - Closed-fist punch to the sternum (as with 5-6).
- 11 - Hammerfist to the bridge of the nose (I believe he told us that the traditional target was the top of the head or the forehead, as with the stick or blade strike, but that it was a bad idea due to how tough the skull is versus the hand)
- 12 - Punch to the orbital socket of the eye (alternately, a poke with the first two fingers,  but he advised against that one due to the risk of missing the eye and breaking one's fingers)

Heh, funny how many memories came back trying to remember the sequence there. It's been a while.

Comment: please elaborate on the targets.  For example, I assume neck for 1 & 2, but can't think of an effective target for a knife-hand for 3 & 4.

Comment: also, do the hands alternate, or is it the same hand for each strike as with stick and knife

Comment: this is a good answer.  i'll leave it open for a few days before I accept though.  thanks, Sean.

Comment: Thank you. I will note that this was over a decade ago, and the instructor in question was fond of incorporating whatever worked into his teaching, so there may be a more official answer. Under interesting links I ran into trying to find a more canonical answer, the differing 12 strikes of FMA: http://arniseskrimamalang.wordpress.com/apa-itu-beladiri-filipina/basic-angles-strike-of-different-style/

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the link!  It shows several different styles of the 12 angles.